# NSArray to NSMutableArray as random stack

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

Just a conceptual description first:

I am reading input from a text file (a list of words) and putting these words into an `NSArray` using `componentsSeparatedByString` method.  This works.

But I wanted to select the words randomly and then delete them from the array so as to ensure a different word each time.  Of course, you cannot change the `NSArray` contents.  So...

I copied the contents of the `NSArray` into an `NSMutableArray` and use IT for the selection source.  This also works - 269 objects in each array.

To return a word from the `NSMutableArray` I use the following code:
note- the arrays are declared globally
    as

```
arrMutTextWords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  //stack for words 
arrTextWords = [[NSArray alloc] init];  //permanent store for words


-(NSString*) getaTextWord
{

// if the mutable text word array is empty refill

if ([arrMutTextWords count] == 0){

    for (int i = 0 ; i < [arrTextWords count]; i++) 
        [arrMutTextWords addObject:[arrTextWords objectAtIndex:i]];
}

int i = random() % [arrMutTextWords count];
NSString* ptrWord = [arrMutTextWords objectAtIndex:i];
[arrMutTextWords removeObjectAtIndex:i];
return ptrWord;
```

}

The program crashes during a call to the method above - here is the calling code:
arrTmp is declared globally arrTmp = [[NSArray alloc] init];  //tmp  store for words

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < 4; i++) {
    tmpWord = [self getaTextWord];
    [arrTmp addObject:tmpWord];
    [arrTmp addObject:tmpWord];
}
```

I'm thinking that somehow deleting strings from `arrMutTextWords` is invalidating the `NSArray` - but I can't think how this would occur.

Comment: Make sure you add four spaces before every line of code -- it looks like some of your code isn't being treated as such by the StackOverflow edit control.

Answer (score 4):

One possible source for problems is your fetching AND removing the `NSString` object from your list. Removing it releases that `NSString` instance therefore devalidating your reference.

To be shure to retain a reference you should use this code sequence instead:

```
NSString * ptrWord = [[[arrMutTextWords objectAtIndex:i] retain] autorelease];
[arrMutTextWords removeObjectAtIndex:i];
return ptrWord;
```

By the way: You should use

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: array];
```

instead of copying all values by hand. While i do not know the implementation of `NSMutableArray`, i know from times long ago (NeXTstep), that there are several possible optimizations that may speed up basic `NSArray` operations.

And finally copying this way is much more concise.

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt reply.  I will check it out.  Can you give me some info sources where i might read up on this issue?

Comment: There is a section on the memory Management behaviour for NSArray and NSMutableArray in the NSArray Class References which deals with this topic.
Additional i would recommend the "Collections Programming Topics for Cocoa" which i read on a regular basis any time i'll get back from Java to Objective-C.

Comment: It worked perfectly!!!  It's obvious I need to bone up on memory management...  I'll be checking out those references.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Just ran this through XCode and got random words returned, however I skipped the whole for loop and used `addObjectsFromArray`from `NSMutableArray`.

```
NSArray *randomArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Paul", @"George", @"John", nil];
NSMutableArray *muteArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[muteArray addObjectsFromArray:randomArray];

int i = random() % [muteArray count];
NSString* ptrWord = [muteArray objectAtIndex:i];
[muteArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
NSLog(@"ptrWord %@", ptrWord); //gave me a different name each time I ran the function.
```

Hope this clears some things up.

Comment: Yep that addObjectsFromArray is handy - I'll use it from now on.